# Wrap shortcode inside custom block

Tags: shortcode, block-editor

I use this shortcode very often: `[foo]123[/foo]`.

I'd like to drag and drop a custom block in the block editor, instead of typing the shortcode (and making typos).

So how do I create a custom block, that just wraps that shortcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First Add a normal Shortcode block and type the shortcode [foo]123[/foo]
2. Then click More Options for the block and select Add to Reusable Blocks
3. Then provide a name as Foo
4. Next, time you can search and add the Foo block instead of typing the shortcode

Thanks

Comment: I actually wanted a programmatic way to do this, but I see I didn't put that in the question. So your answer is valid. Thanks.

Comment: I see. I didnt get that idea from the question. There should be a way to do it. Havent tried yet. Will update if i have time to check and find a solution

Comment: Don't worry, your answer is valid for this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to do this via code: use the `do_shortcode('[your-shortcode-name-here]')` function. It's drop-dead simple. The doc is at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/.

You can use a filter hook with the do_shortcode() function to make pretty much anything in WordPress shortcode-capable. For example, to enable shortcodes in the post titles, do this: `add_filter('the_title', 'do_shortcode')`